# Mirror traffic from x network card to VMware player

Tags: nic, isa-server

I have 2 Network cards and I am trying to monitor traffic going through one of them (the internet facing one), so that I can see what sites are visited the most and how much data is being used.

I'v installed Debian on VMware player but I can't find a way to access the traffic from that one NIC.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Vmware player. But I think it's similar to Vmware workstation.

Configure your guest OS network with [bridge](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_bridged.html) mode.

When you configured guest OS with bridge mode/with network configuration/, there are too many traffic monitoring [tools](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/networktools2.htm) available in Debian.